# org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code '' for locale 'en'

Tags: java

I am using Spring MVC to develop one application to display error message i done changes in spring-servlet.xml like below

```
<bean id="messageSource"    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames" value="classpath:resources/ApplicationResources,/>
<property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/> 
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
</bean>
```

But still i am getting 
No message found under code '' for locale 'en' exception,
can someone help me in this issue.

Comment: Try to remove "," after "classpath:resources/ApplicationResources"

Comment: Actually i have more than one property thats why , is there after last i ended the tag also

Comment: i have more than one property file after ApplicationResource one more file is there